# GitKraken - Delete Account

Tags: git, gitkraken

Does anyone know how to delete an account in [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/)? I have searched the whole web for instructions but did not find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Click [gitkraken account](https://account.gitkraken.com) to go to account, or click `Manage Account` from the user menu dropdown in-app.

[image: gitkraken account]

In `Manage Users` on a subscription, click `Delete` next to the user on the list followed by Remove User for confirmation to remove a user and free up a license.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can now go directly to https://app.gitkraken.com/account-info/delete-account to delete your account